# What does this formal sentence mean for the given interpretation?

Tags: logic

[screenshot of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6vTR.png)
If the domain is the natural numbers and R(x,y) is interpreted as ("x is the square of y"), I would interpret ∀X∃yR(y,x) as meaning "the square of any natural number is a natural number".

[image: screenshot of question]

However, the correct interpretation of sentence b is apparently "every natural number has a square root that is a natural number". Why is this? To ensure I haven't just misread something, I've included screenshots of the question and answer (this is from a practice exam for a philosophy course)

[image: screenshot of answer]

Comment: I agree with you.  As stated, (b) says that the square of any natural number is a natural number.  One possible explanation for the "correct" interpretation is that there is a typo.  Note that the relation is written as "Ry,x" in (b), rather than "Rx,y".  If they meant to say "Rx,y" then their "correct" answer would hold.

Comment: Thank you! I was really  concerned that I couldn't answer such a basic question

Comment: You are correct. The provided answer is not.